# How selective are companies in the US, about the institute the student graduated from?

Tags: job-offer

Are companies in the US very selective about the institute/University the student graduated from? Or will they give the job to the student, if he has the right skills but is from a 2nd/3rd tier college.(I mean, not ivy league)

If this is not the right stack exchange site, please mention

Comment: @JoeStrazzere okay, so, in general, are there people on both sides? Or is the whole country biased a lot, towards any one side.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I forgot to read the last part of your reply. I'm thinking of a job in the IT industry. Maybe a software job, or a ML job,etc

Comment: Some are. Especially finance and law

Answer (score 3):

The fact that in my career I have run into only a handful of people who have a degree from an Ivy, I assume that people without a degree from an IVY league school have no problems finding jobs.

I have also run into many employees who only have a degree from a community college, or a for-profit college. That means that they also can find jobs.

While it is possible that an Ivy league degree gets you an interview in those first few years after college, you still have to get past the interview process.

There are some positions and companies that believe that an ivy league school is the minimum threshold, but those make up only a small number of positions.

Comment: Just for some more information, are talking about the IT/software industry?

Comment: Yes. This over 30+ years in the scientific, computers, and government industries.

Comment: Some jobs prefer Ivy graduates.  It is more to do with the company than the industry.  For example, a predictive analytics company I worked at liked people from Rice.  In the same town UofH graduated tons more people, but the owner was from Rice, the board was mostly from Rice, and the better prestige / paying jobs were mostly populated from Rice graduates.  Required?  No.  But some industries (like finance) might care, for people just entering the field.  What is clear though is that most people can get in with a non-Ivy degree, they just have to work harder.

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

1. The older your degree, the less relevant it is. Once you are 3+ years into your career, your recent work experience and achievements far outweigh the academics by a wide margin
2. It can be advantage for new grads. There isn't a whole of useful data in a resume that early in your career and all other things being equal the people sorting the resumes will probably bias well known colleges (or colleges that the hiring manager prefers) higher on the stack. That doesn't necessarily mean Ivy League but colleges that have very good programs in the specific field
3. In 100s of interviews and hiring decisions I was involved in, it never impacted the actual hiring decisions. It may help you get the interview, but what you do and say in the interview is way more important.
4. One of the worst performers in an engineering department that I ran was an MIT graduate.
5. Hiring has become very global these days and so there is less focus on US university degrees. Actually it's a bit on the contrary:  The quality of engineering candidates from US colleges (reputable or not) has dropped significantly (to put it mildly) over the last 10-15 years, so it can actually be a downside

Comment: Okay, so, do most of the companies allow on ivy league students to sit for their interviews? Or is it just a few is the companies?

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi I'm not aware of any company that *only* recruits from Ivy Leagues.  The IT majors (FAANG) explicitly recruit "diverse" candidates from any background, as long as they have enough relevant experience to get to the interview stage.

Comment: @SwaroopJoshi no company restricts interviews to candidates from high profile universities. However you typically get way more resumes for a position that you can invite for an interview. Hence there is some sorting that happens based on the resume alone. This sorting looks at a variety of factors including your university. But it's just that: one data point among many others

Comment: @Hilmar - do you have a source for your comment that the quality of engineering candidates from US colleges is declining? That is a concerning trend (to put it mildly)

Comment: @Noel : mostly a lot of personal interviewing and hiring experience including some extreme examples like a professor from a well known university that didn't even know the basics of the calls they were teaching. Related reading: https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2015/09/the-coddling-of-the-american-mind/399356/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean "well known" schools as oppose to top level Ivy leagues like Harvard, Yale, etc.

Certain industries do care about it. I think Blue Collar workers are more susceptible to the whole degree thing. For example, at this car parts manufacturer my family works at, having a BS degree from a well known university will get you bumped up to management levels pretty quickly.

However, I think white collar level, I see a lot of folks having associates degree and making it pretty far in their field. I also think it depends on where you get a job. At a company or something big like a job at a huge research department, NASA, or something like that? I think in those cases your degree may be under scrutiny than compared to something like some web company.